# Building a Nice GUI in C language

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I am developing a software using C language. I would like to build a nice graphical user interface to get the input and present the output as well as the progress status. The console is OK when it comes to test the software but to attract attention when presenting my software to other,  I need something better. Any ideas.. Thanks!

I am using : Visual Studio 2010 on Windows7.

Comment: Create a dialog resource and call [`DialogBoxParam`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to display it.

Comment: There's nothing in plain [tag:c] that will let you build a GUI. You need to use a library of some kind that interfaces with platform-specific APIs to get input and display graphics. Which library to use will ultimately be opinion-based.  If you add [tag:WinAPI] to your question, that could help scope your answers, but there will still be a huge range of options available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hat's off for sticking with C for this, it's kinda the hard way!

Anyway, you could link to the Win32 Api and create a GUI that way.
http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html

Another option would be to use a cross platform framework like GTK+: http://www.gtk.org/